# Open sitecore media library programmatically from asp.net button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitecore

I have been trying to figure out if it is possible to open the Sitecore media library browser programmatically from ASP.NET code-behind on a server-side button click. By searching the net, I found [an example which explained how to open a media library browser](http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/kevin/archive/2011/09/13/building-the-thumbnail-button-module.aspx) from a Sitecore thumbnail click. I tried this approach on ASP.NET server-side button click but it did not work failing with `object reference not set to an instance of an object`.

Can anyone please help me if you know how to open the Sitecore media browser in a modal dialog via a server side button click?

My code:

```
protected void btnShowMediaPopup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Database masterDb = Factory.GetDatabase("master");
    UrlString url = new UrlString(UIUtil.GetUri("control:Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Media.MediaBrowser"));

    Item folderItem = masterDb.GetItem("/sitecore/media library/Images");
    url["ro"] = folderItem.Uri.ToString();

    SheerResponse.ShowModalDialog(url.ToString(), true);   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. Steps as follows:

a. Created config file "MediaBrowser.config"  and added into folder App_Config/Include (configuration xml below):

> ```
> <configuration xmlns:patch= "http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
>   <sitecore>
>       <commands>
>           <command name="example:MediaBrowser" type="SitecoreTraining.HelperClasses.MediaBrowser,SitecoreTraining" />
>       </commands>
>   </sitecore>
> </configuration>
> ```

b. In my ascx control markup added the following to open the media browser:

```
<A class="scChromeCommand" title="Open Media Browser" onclick="javascript:Sitecore.PageModes.ChromeManager.postRequest('example:MediaBrowser(id=<%# Sitecore.Context.Item.ID.ToString() %>)',null,false)" href="#"><IMG alt="Open Media Browser" src="http://localhost:2438/temp/IconCache/applications/16x16/photo_scenery.png" width="16" height="16" /></A>
```

c. Created a MediaBrowser class that inherits the sitecore Command class with the following main methods used:

> public override void Execute(CommandContext context)
>   {
>
> ```
>         Item item = context.Items.Length == 0 ? Context.Item : context.Items[0];
>         contextItem = item;
>
>         var parameters = new NameValueCollection();
>
>         wizardPipeline = Context.ClientPage.Start(this, "Run", parameters);
>     }
> ```
>
> protected virtual void Run(ClientPipelineArgs args)
>           {
>
> ```
>         Database  masterDb = Factory .GetDatabase("master");      
>         if  (args.IsPostBack)     
>         {         
>             var itemID = args.Result;   
>         }     
>         else      
>         {         
>             UrlString  url = new  UrlString (UIUtil .GetUri("control:Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Media.MediaBrowser" ));  
>
>             Item  folderItem = masterDb.GetItem("/sitecore/media library/Images" );         
>             url["ro" ] = folderItem.Uri.ToString();                  
>             SheerResponse.ShowModalDialog(url.ToString(), true );         
>             args.WaitForPostBack(true );     
>         }
>     }
> ```