# Open Upload Media Dialog via Custom Field

Tags: c#, sitecore, sitecore7.2

We want to upload the media to **Amazon S3** via **Sitecore** & save the path of the uploaded media to the custom field.

So we created a **custom field**,which has a menu button to upload the media.

Here's my custom field class:

```
public class ExternalImage : Edit
{      
    public ExternalImage()
    {
        this.Class = "scContentControl";
    }
    public override void HandleMessage(Message message)
    {
        Assert.ArgumentNotNull(message, "message");
        base.HandleMessage(message);
        string name;
        if (message["id"] == this.ID && (name = message.Name) != null)
        {
            if (name == "externalimage:open")
            {
                // Need help to open media upload popup here
            }                
        }
    }                     
}
```

**UPDATE**

After some research I came to know that I need to call/invoke the media:upload command within the code,so here is what I did(without any success ):

```
 if (name == "externalimage:open")
 { 
     string text = "media:upload(load=1,tofolder=1,id={3D6658D8-A0BF-4E75-B3E2-D050FABCF4E1})";
     var item2 = Client.ContentDatabase.GetItem("{3D6658D8-A0BF-4E75-B3E2-D050FABCF4E1}");
     Command command = CommandManager.GetCommand(text);
     if (command == null)
     {
         SheerResponse.Alert(Translate.Text("Edit command not found."), new string[0]);
         return;
     }
     CommandState commandState = CommandManager.QueryState(text, item2);

     command.Execute(new CommandContext(item2));
     return;
}
```

Comment: You're probably looking at using the [Sheer UI](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Articles/XML%20Sheer%20UI.aspx) and writing a custom dialog to present to the user (assuming I'm understanding correctly).

Comment: Yes I want to open a custom dialog with file upload control.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open sitecore media library programmatically from asp.net button click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9154475/open-sitecore-media-library-programmatically-from-asp-net-button-click)

Comment: @nsgocev No,I'm not trying to open the media library in code,so it's not same as the link you provided.