# Open sitecore media library from asp.net button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore8.1

I have followed the method which is answered in the link
[Open sitecore media library programmatically from asp.net button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9154475/open-sitecore-media-library-programmatically-from-asp-net-button-click)

while calling the command to open media gallery

```
<asp:Button ID="btn_media" runat="server" Text="Media Browser" onclick="javascript:Sitecore.PageModes.ChromeManager.postRequest('example:MediaBrowser(id=<%# Sitecore.Context.Item.ID.ToString() %>)',null,false)"/>
```

But still not able to open media library.

I am getting an error "Sitecore is Undefined"
Can anyone please help me if you know how to open the Sitecore media browser on aspx button click?

Comment: Looks like you're missing references, Sitecore.Kernal.DLL at the very least.

Comment: The error you are seeing is because there is no reference to `Sitecore.js` and related script libraries in your ASP.Net page. Are you running this code in Experience Editor mode or elsewhere?